# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'init_scope'

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection-api

How do we resolve the above error while running the object detection api training locally

Installed the Object detection api in ubuntu and tried training locally

Steps for running the training job locally:
https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/running_locally.md

Steps i followed for installation:
https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/installation.md

Job has to start successfully and provide loss

Comment: Which version of Tensorflow are you using?

Comment: tensorflow=1.13 python 2.7